# Microsoft Graph API - $search query returns same result repeatedly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I only have 15-20 messages in my inbox for June 20. But when I run a search query for that day

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$search=" received = 2019/06/20"&$select=from,id&$top=1000
```

I am seeing that the results are repeating, meaning the same message id keeps circling back (think its an infinitely) and the results take several seconds to return.

I am even able to reproduce that with Graph explorer. It doesn't seem to happen for other days in my inbox. I think I have come across some bug in the system but unclear what exactly it is.

Anyone know what it is?

Comment: could provide a request-id given back in the response for the request please? We can do some investigation in the service that way if there are any errors.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT here you go - 07612474-6ece-4fe0-87ad-43253dd9a0a4
thanks for looking

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT Is there a public ticket I can follow? Or do you know when you may have some updates?

Comment: we will  respond here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed. Can you pls try again?

Comment: great! i can't repro this issue in the graph explorer anymore. do you mind explaining what the bug was?

Comment: It was a bug that has now been fixed.